# Add a "Start" button after Main menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a wordpress menu and I want to add a button to the extreme right of the main menu. My theme is responsive, and I don't want the button the move into the dropdown when I resize the page either, and that is why I do not want this button to be part of the menu, it should be outside of it.

An example of what I want to do is on [PistonCloud](http://www.pistoncloud.com) . Notice the Start button on the extreme right, and it still shows up on smaller screens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a "nav" element in the header.php file, or in a custom header file if you are using a customized theme. Append the div/button/hyperlink or any other custom code you want right before the closing of the "nav" element.